# How do I access a specific file on a Windows share?

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing

In Ubuntu, I would like to know **How do I access a specific file on a Windows share?**

In Windows XP I could the use `Run Command >>\\someserver` but Im not sure what the equivilent options are in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

```
nautilus "smb://someserver/share/path/to/file"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu. If you are satisfied by the answer, please do accept the answer with the tick-mark present next to the answer :)